# Close element once you click another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi Honestly speaking Guys i need your help again, what im trying to do is the script below showing a overlay once you click the menu and what im trying to do is on the menu i have a modal contact form once i click it a close icon or anchor shows up what im trying to do is when you click the close button from the contact form the overlay will close as well.

The id for it is **"closepls"**
The js below is creating an element which is overlay, and what im trying to do is when you click the close button on the modal it will close as well or remove thank you

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<!-- This is the close button -->
    <div class="close-modal" id="closepls" data-dismiss="modal">
       <p class="cl"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> ClOSE</p>

    </div>



     <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">


            <!-- First Div -->
             <div class="col-md-6 conone condits">

             <h1> Sample Heading 

            </div>

            <!-- END First Div -->


            <!-- Second Div -->

             <div class="col-md-6 conone">
                                            <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
                   <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="52" title="send"]' ); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- END Second Div -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Js

```
<script> 
 init=()=>{
        //SELECT & BIND (CLICK) EVENT
        document.querySelector('a.menuToggle, a#welcomeDivs').addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.init);
    }
    modal={
        overlay:{
            init:()=>{
                //CREATE OVERLAY 
                var overlay = document.createElement('overlay');
                overlay.id = 'welcomeDivsss';
                //SET (CLICK) EVENT TO REMOVE ITSLEF
                overlay.addEventListener('click',modal.overlay.remove);

                //APPEND TO INTERFACE
                document.body.appendChild(overlay);

                // After overlay added to html. "welcomeDivsss" is overlay id you specified.
                $( "#welcomeDivsss" ).append( '<div class="parela" id="welcomeDiv" <div class="inner_box"> <a onclick="click" class="closes"></a> </div> </div>' );

            },
            remove:(e)=>{
                //REMOVE ITSELF
                e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
                document.getElementById('welcomeDivsss').remove();
                //Trying to make it happen using this code below 
                document.getElementById('closepls').remove();

            }       
        }
    }

    //ON DOCUMENT LOAD RUN INIT
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);

</script>
```

Comment: Add `onclick="modal.overlay.remove()"` to `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

```
$(function(){
    $('#closepls').click(function(){
                document.getElementById('welcomeDivsss').remove();
    });
});
```